# Ejabberd- set vard for other user

Tags: ejabberd

Is it possible to add a vcard for some other jabber user in ejabberd. I am logged in as admin@domain.com. While creating users in my website i am registering a jabber account for the same user. Now i need to add vcards for those users. While trying to add vcard for a new user, i can see that the vcard entry is added to the currently logged in user(in my case it is `admin@domain.com`). I am using strophe library and the code used for adding vcard is as follows.

`iq = $iq({ type: 'set', to: 'user@domain.com' }).c('vCard', { xmlns:'vcard-temp' }).c('PHOTO').c('EXTVAL', 'http://image_url/image.jpg');
conn.sendIQ(iq);`

But i can achieve the same using
`ejabberdctl set_vcard jabber_id domain PHOTO img.jpg` from CLI

The purpose is to add profile images to users. I have the profile images saved in my server for each users registered in my site. Currently i am doing an ajax call for fetching the user profile image. Is there any alternative for this? Any help will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

XMPP protocol does not define a way to edit vcard for other users and ejabberd does not implement something special to allow this.

You can use a database backend for Vcard or write a custom Vcard backend plugin to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try with a custom plugin.